# Sum values in one column of all rows which match one or more of multiple criteria

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have some table data in which I'd like to sum all the values in a specific column of all rows where column A contains string A and/or column B contains string B. How can I achieve this?

This works for one criterium:

```
=SUM(FILTER(G:G,REGEXMATCH(F:F,"stringA")))
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
=SUM(FILTER(G:G,OR(ISTEXT(REGEXMATCH(F:F,"stringA")),ISTEXT(REGEXMATCH(C:C,"stringB")))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

`=SUM(FILTER(G:G,REGEXMATCH(F:F,"stringA")+REGEXMATCH(C:C,"stringB")))`

[image]

`+` works for `or` logic. `ISTEXT` is not needed because `REGEXMATCH` gives true or false.

`OR` does not work because `filter` is an `arrayformula`, use `+` in array formulas.

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUM(FILTER(G:G,REGEXMATCH(F:F&C:C,"stringA|stringB")))
```

OR is denoted by `|`

> **EDIT**     Added `&C:C` to denote different Columns

Comment: This is good to know, but my criteria are for different columns.

Comment: Just add `&C:C`

Comment: Oh, now that's really useful. Thanks! I wish I could accept two answers. :)

Comment: @Nathan :) Max's answer is more specific though. Mine will sum as long as there's a string A or string B in the concatenated columns "F"&"C". Which means C column can contain stringA instead of stringB and F column may contain string B instead of string A... but as long as the concatenated entry contains A or B strings, it'll sum up G.